# Hyperledger Composer v0.19.8 Error When Upgrading Business Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to upgrade hyperledger fabric business network and I get this error

```
composer archive create -t dir -n . && \
composer network install -a $BNA_FILE -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 && \
composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n NETWORK-NAME -V 0.1.23
```

The version number corresponds to that one in the `package.json` like the documentation says it should. I get the below error when I run the upgrade command

```
Error: Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses 
from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode 
error (status: 500, message: could not find chaincode with name 'NETWORK-NAME')
```

I made sure that hyperledger fabric is running `./startFabric` yet I still get this error

Comment: It's telling you that there is no business network started called NETWORK-NAME. What was the name of the network you installed and started and are now trying to upgrade to ? that is what should be the value of the -n parameter

Comment: The network name is NETWORK-NAME, and it shows up linked to it's chard when I run `composer card list`

Comment: If that is the correct business network name, then what has happened between you originally starting that business network and then trying to upgrade it, because fabric is saying there is no chaincode with that name instantiated on the blockchain.

Comment: I executed the `teardownAllDocker.sh` script, and then `./startFabric` and it worked. The problem that I am now facing is that `upgrade` command only works once after I restart all services, otherwise it throws an exception

Comment: If you restart the development fabric, then your chaincode is lost which explains why the upgrade fails (there is no business network started as you have a clean fabric). You need to install and do a start again

Comment: It only works after I have restarted fabric services, and it works once after that. I have started the network successfully and upgrade still gives me problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174287/discussion-between-mohale-and-david-k).

Answer (score 2):

The error message received is saying that there is no business network called `NETWORK-NAME` started. In order to upgrade a business network it has to have been previously started.

What it sounds like in this case is that you have started the simple fabric development server provided by composer and initially installed and started the business network `NETWORK-NAME`. At some point you have restarted the fabric but this restart has actually removed the existing fabric servers and created a new fresh fabric network. Because this is a clean fabric network, there now isn't a business network on the channel and you need to start again from scratch and install and start the business network. For example the `startFabric.sh` script actually completely removes your existing fabric network and creates a new one and as such the business network and data is lost.

These resources may help you if you want to look into ensuring your fabric server persists it's information under various circumstances.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#a-note-on-data-persistence

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#fabricsetup (see section on how to retain docker state)

Comment: Something does not add up, the same commands that I have been using all along are now working, The [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/upgrading-bna) on step 4 of the guide does say the network must be started, but that is not shown as a step on its own(I hope I make sense). The same commands that were not working are now working without any modification. I guess restarting the VM that I am using might have also contributed