# Updating composer file -- (status: 500, message: could not find chaincode with name 'xxx')

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm trying to update a .bna file, however, I'm facing this issue when I run the following command :

composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n xxx -V 0.0.2

it says the following :

```
Upgrading business network definition. This may take a minute...
```

Error: Error trying to upgrade business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: could not find chaincode with name 'wecashup')
Command failed

I sincerely don't know to resolve that, I've already updated the version on my json file ...but still the same errors.

```
{
```

"engines": {
    "composer": "^0.19.13"
  },
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "WecashUp blockchain",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "mkdirp ./dist && composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/wecashup.bna",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "nyc mocha -t 0 test/*.js && cucumber-js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "composer",
    "composer-network"
  ],
  "author": "Paris",
  "email": "parismollochristondis@gmail.com",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "composer-admin": "^0.19.13",
    "composer-cli": "^0.19.13",
    "composer-client": "^0.19.13",
    "composer-common": "^0.19.13",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.19.13",
    "composer-cucumber-steps": "^0.19.13",
    "chai": "latest",
    "chai-as-promised": "latest",
    "cucumber": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "nyc": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest"
  }
}

My composer version is 19.13

Comment: Have you run the command `composer network install` to install the new code onto the Peer before starting it?

Or have you run the startFabric.sh script since running the install command?

Comment: I start by startfabric (after cleaning the docker) and then I install on the PeerAdmin and only after all that I execute the upgrade the command

Comment: The solution is the explained on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155970/hyperledger-composer-v0-19-8-error-when-upgrading-business-network#comment89297120_51155970